# Unable to resolve an inherited nested static class during compilation

Tags: java, grails, groovy

The story is quite short and it starts with the few following excerpts from Lucene's classes:

Analyzer:

```
public abstract class Analyzer implements Closeable {

    (...)

    public static class TokenStreamComponents { ... }

    (...)
}
```

AnalyzerWrapper:

```
public abstract class AnalyzerWrapper extends Analyzer {

    (...)

    @Override
    protected final TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader aReader) {
        return wrapComponents(fieldName, getWrappedAnalyzer(fieldName).createComponents(fieldName, aReader));
    }

    (...)

}
```

Now inside a Grails application I define my own class, `MyAnalyzer.groovy`

```
class MyAnalyzer extends AnalyzerWrapper {

    private final PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper perFieldAnalyzerWrapper

    public MyAnalyzer() { ... }

    @Override
    protected Analyzer getWrappedAnalyzer(String fieldName) {
        perFieldAnalyzerWrapper.getWrappedAnalyzer(fieldName)
    }

    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents wrapComponents(String fieldName, TokenStreamComponents tokenStreamComponents) {
        perFieldAnalyzerWrapper.wrapComponents(fieldName, tokenStreamComponents)
    }
}
```

And when I try to run/compile the application, I get:

```
[groovyc] Compiling 2 source files to E:\somewhere\...\target\classes
[groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
[groovyc] E:\somewhere\...\MyAnalyzer.groovy: 31: unable to resolve class TokenStreamComponents 
[groovyc]  @ line 31, column 5.
[groovyc]        @Override
[groovyc]        ^
[groovyc] 
[groovyc] 1 error
```

However, if I change both occurences of `TokenStreamComponents` to `Analyzer.TokenStreamComponents` in the definition of the overridden method in `MyAnalyzer`, the class compiles fine.

Does anyone know if there is some logical reason behind such behavior, caused e.g. by the way Groovy or Grails behaves, or am I just missing something here?

Comment: Have you tried importing the inner class?

Comment: The fun with importing the inner class is that my IDE removes it automatically, because it determines that it's unnecessary. And anyway I shouldn't be required to import it or do anything special, since it should be available in the scope.

Comment: But to answer your question - importing `org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.TokenStreamComponents` also makes it compile.

Comment: I think that is just the way it behaves.  I've run into this when working with `Map` and `Map.Entry` from `java.util`.

Comment: Groovy's import behavior is mirroring Java's. It works the way it does because import only works on classes: it does not directly handle packages or class members, so you have to be specific. (Wildcards being an exception.) You can get it to work by using `import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.TokenStreamComponents` or `import static org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.*`. Your IDE is screwing up if it is deleting a valid import; I've never seen this in Eclipse or IDEA.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the line import Analyzer.*; to the import section of your Program. ! let me know if it solved.!

Comment: Had same problem with Map.Entry class. Solved using explicit import java.util.Map.Entry